# Dark ActionBar in Holo Dark

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am developing an Android app on Android Studio and I would like to use the Holo Dark theme but in the KitKat version, I mean, how it appears on the picture I attach below.

[image]

I'm testing the app on a KitKat AVD, and in the manifest the maximum and target SDK version is 19, but the action bar is like in the pic below:

[image]

I just want to get the design like in the first image, so if anyone knows how, please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the Solid ActionBar:

```
<style name="Theme.Whatever" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.Solid</item>
</style>
```

Comment: It worked, but I have to set the minSdkVersion to 14. Is there any way to use this with a minSdkVersion of 8?

Comment: You should try the ActionBar from the support library and this should work: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomBackground7
However, I'd like to point out the fact that as of today, 99.2% of devices use API>=10. And almost 85% use API>=15. Source: https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html